# Using database to store webpage contents(text, code snippets,images so on)

Tags: php, css, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to use database to store webpage contents(text, code snippets,images so on) in a single field. What I want to do is to store the web page data along with formats in the DB and to display on the webpage with the original format. Is there way I can do this?

Comment: what you tried so far?  Stack is willing to help you when you got strucked  and not to give opinions

Comment: Thanks for the message Abdulla! I am stuck at a point where I don't understand the way the contents along with the formats are maintained in database. I am using  text area to store the contents but how do I go about making sure that CSS is also preserved along with the data in database?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Database is only used for storing the data, not the whole HTML codes.

Comment: Hi Afif, All I want to do is to store the contents in database with the styles so when I retrieve them to display they should not lost any styles. Any idea you can share with me?

Comment: Actually i didn't understand your issue. Are you looking for CMS(Content management system) website

Comment: @Yadhu, Although I don't know how CMS works, I know wordpress is one such. But I just needed to find a way to store the HTML document in database which will be output when the webpage is accessed. So, instead of maintaining contents and structure in a file system, I looked to store in a database. Do you think it is worthwhile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass all your code as string into your database, although it's a rather inconvenient way of storing your pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Your answer helped get closer to what I needed! Could you please tell me of the convenient way of storing the webpages except for the file system?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with pages. If you want to protect your code/data and keep it hidden, I'd recommend you take a look at MVC or MVVM patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the message. I am working with codeigniter!